# jquery Easytabs Back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am using easytabs bootstrap tabs and when you cycle through the tabs, then tries to go back to the last page it takes you back to the last tab you were on not the last page. I don't want that.

Is there any js that will allow me to remove the hash and allow users to go to the previous page when the back button is clicked instead of the previous tab.

Here is an example link:
http://www.whitewatermarine.ns.ca/new-boats/2013-princecraft-vantage-21-package

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the api for jquery.easytabs, here is what I used;

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs({
    panelContext: $(document),    
    updateHash: false, 
});
```